# running process with gitlab ci

Tags: windows, .net-core, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab runner installed on one of my test servers.
I want to build and deploy my app on every commit.
The server is a windows server and the app is a .net core 1.1 app.

my build script works fine but eventually it runs `dotnet MyApp.dll` which obviously makes the pipeline stop wait until it finishes (but, of course, my app won't finish, I want it to run..)

I tried running `start dotnet MyApp.dll` but that still doesn't work as gitlab's runner won't stop running until all of it's child processes exit.

I am certain I'm using gitlab's CI in a non idiomatic way but fail to understand how to deploy locally correctly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows doesn't offer any easy way to disown a process and you probably don't want to task yourself with stopping the process on your next deploy. What you should do is use [SRVANY.EXE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/137890/how-to-create-a-user-defined-service) to create service out of your application and then use the Gitlab CI to stop the service, replace the files and run it again. It's been a while since I used Windows so I'm sorry but I can't provide the exact commands to run.

Comment: Yeah this will work. Specifically I think I'll use nssm instead of srvany. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @user3142398 When you resolve it you may add further instructions as answer for others.